# WPF async Loaded with UI elements

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I need to hide certain controls on Loaded routed event, and when I start an async task. To eliminate writing two methods for same thing I created async Loaded event and call only async Task for this, but I also need to change Content of two UI StatusBarItems, which can't be in my async method for hiding controls.

I've stumbled upon example like this a few times before, and figured that async/await allows you to update UI directly as long as you call await in same method.

I'm allways in doubt when doing that, so I need to clarify myself If **is this a legit thing to do in async/await or is It a very bad practice?**

Here is my example of what I mean:

```
 private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      //Controls on UI thread - I change their content
      StatusBarItem1.Content = "Some Text";
      StatusBarItem2.Content = "Test Text";

      await HideControls(); //Asynchronous task

 }

 private async Task HideControls()
 {
      await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
      {
          //Hide controls in UI Thread
          var All_labels = My_Grid.Children.OfType<Label>();

          foreach (var item in All_Labels)
          {
             item.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
          }

          TextBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

      }));

  }
```

EDIT (button_click event):

```
  private async void Btn_Check_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
            //First hide controls - if user allready cliked this button
            await HideControls();

            //running all tasks one at a time - Task.Delay() between them. In order to keep smoooth UI design
            await Task1();
            await Task2();
            await Task3();
            await Task4();
            await Task5();
   }
```

Thanks for answers in advance !

Comment: I don't think there is a definitive yes or no answer to your question, it depends a lot on context. What is sure is that you need to be careful to be in the UI thread while you do UI modification.

Your example is probably not a terrific example as you don't do anything after your `Task.Delay` so it's hard to see what use you would have of your method being async. Do you have a more concrete example where you want to change UI stuff after an await?

Comment: @Gimly, yes I know this is a simple example, but It's a real one. This posted example is just a part where I call async method on Loaded event. Other part is where I execute 4 different async Tasks via Async Button_click, and to be able to run this Button_click as many times as I want I need to hide these controls too -  before all Async Tasks, in order to reset all  controls to same point as they were when window loaded.

Comment: But what's the advantage of having your method wait 1s before returning? Since the code that modify the UI needs to be in the UI thread, it will block the UI anyway while it's doing its work, so the async has no use.

Comment: @Gimly, ooohhh I see. Sorry that was a typo, I use Task.Delay() in other Tasks which I haven't posted, not here. I use that in order to run Tasks smothly one after another, just a UI design.I've edited question.

Comment: Isn't the "proper" way using MVVM? Anyway, for quick / small programs, I do it dirty like you do.

Comment: @SILENT, yes It's a small app. It only get's result of 4 four time consuming DB queries, to inform user about certain things. All Async code is just for smooth running ... About MVVM - I'm still learning this, quite different topic to discuss :)

Comment: According to the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types) your `HideControls` method should be named `HideControlsAsync`. But why do you need an asynchronous method? What problem are you solving by hiding the controls through the `Dispatcher`, instead of hiding them directly in a synchronous method?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, read upper posts. I have Async Button_Click, there is where I need It. But Andy posted correct answer for me.

Comment: Can you include in your question the code in the `async Button_Click` event handler? I believe that you are doing something wrong there, otherwise you wouldn't need all this `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` stuff.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, sure, see edited question. But As I mentioned, Andy answered me allready, so all of this Dispatcher code goes to history.

Comment: I see no reason in the code you provided for the `HideControls` method to be async. It is absolutely normal to have some synchronous code inside an asynchronous method (like the `Button_Click`). It is not required that every line of code should start with an `await`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, that was my initial question but I still think that Andy's solution is still more correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is a bit odd really.

Given that you know mvvm then you presumably know binding would be way simpler than looping through controls.

Whether you're using mvvm or not, I would still think the simple way to do this is bind visibility of all the labels using a style to set the binding.

You put that in the resources of my_grid to set the binding on all labels inside it.
Also bind your one checkbox.

You could use tag of a control which would be a dependency property or one regular property in something implements inpc.

That would be less code.

You then just set the one property on one thing.

Sometimes it's best to await task.delay(20) so it definitely has time to do it's thing.

Then await your task.

Yours above only sets the visibility but the real thing is presumably getting data or something.

Return the results of the task to the ui thread. In pseudo code:

```
var someResults = await yourTask;
```

Hence yourTask is a Task.

Then you're back on the UI thread and can do whatever you need to with someResults.
Often you don't need different threads at all because the reason for delay is 99.9% network and database latency as you read your data off a server. In which case there is almost no "work" for any separate task on the client to do other than hang about until the data comes back to it.

Maybe as an aside.

Inotifypropertychanged change notification is marshalled to the ui thread. Meaning it works in a background thread.

So you could potentially set bound properties on a vm inside a task and it would work.

I don't really like that approach since it's clearer that you're concerned about the ui thread and better encapsulation if the task just returns data.

Here's some quick and dirty markup + code to give you something more concrete.

```
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" >
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Do Something</Button>
    <StackPanel Tag="Visibility.Visible"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Name="sp">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel}}"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Label>Apple</Label>
        <Label>Banana</Label>
        <TextBox Name="TextBox1"
                 Text="This is the TextBox" 
                 Visibility="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel}}"
                 />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Tag is a dependency property so no need for inpc but this is of course quite dirty.

Code behind.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sp.Tag = Visibility.Collapsed;
        var obj = await getSomeObjectAsync();
        // obj would be some dto or something in a real app and you'd do something with it
        sp.Tag = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private static async Task<object> getSomeObjectAsync()
    {
        // You would do something like database access here rather than just delay.
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        return new object();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I was hoping for a bit in-deep answer like yours. I usually did this when doing some simple things and  to this day no users ever had any errors in apps. However, just to confirm all you're saying - could you post a simple example ?

Comment: Iterating controls won't give you any errors. It's just not a very elegant solution given what you can do with wpf. It's also not very flexible.

Comment: superior answer. Thank you so much for this, I finally confirmed my mistakes. Another thing to learn in WPF :)